# {TimeoutError}TimeoutError('Timeout 30000ms exceeded.') Playwright

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I'm facing an issue trying to clicking a locator element. I use this code `page.locator('span[dir="auto"]:has-text("See more comments")').all()` to fetch all locators that match with the selector, and works fine because it retrieves 8 elements. Each element displays a pop-up with info that I need, but using a for loop to iterate over each one, and trying to make a `.click()` on it, results in a `{TimeoutError}TimeoutError('Timeout 30000ms exceeded.')`. Even if I try to click on the first element without retreiving all of them, results in this error. I don't know why this is happening. Hope you can help me.
Here's the code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from mypackages.service import CookiesFacebookService()
from mypackages.utils import Options

class PlaywrightScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.cookiesService = CookiesFacebookService()
        self.options = Options

    @staticmethod
    def set_cookie_fb(cookies):
        list_keys_cookies = []
        for key, value in cookies.items():
            cookie_req = {
                "path": "/",
                "domain": ".facebook.com",
                "sameSite": "Lax",
                "name": key,
                "httpOnly": True,
                "secure": True,
                "value": value
            }
            list_keys_cookies.append(cookie_req)
        return list_keys_cookies

    def prepare_launch_browser(self):
        with sync_playwright() as playwright:
            return self.launch_playwright(playwright=playwright, options_browser=self.options)

    def launch_playwright(self, playwright, options_browser):
        user_cookies = self.cookiesService.getAccountFacebook()[0]["reqCookies"] # Here you can just put a valid facebook cookie in JSON format.
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(**options_browser)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.context.add_cookies(self.set_cookie_fb(user_cookies))
        page.goto("https://www.facebook.com/groups/javascript.react.node", wait_until='load')
        page.mouse.wheel(0, 1000)
        list_of_locators = page.locator('span[dir="auto"]:has-text("See more comments")').all()
        for index in list_of_locators:
            load_more_comments = index
            if load_more_comments is not None:
                page.on("response", self.filter_comment_response)
                load_more_comments.click() ##### ERROR TIMEOUT
                page.wait_for_load_state('load')
                self.counter += 1

    def filter_comment_response(self, response):
        if response.request.method == "POST" and "api/graphql" in response.request.url:
            try:
                text_body = response.body().decode('utf-8')
                final_text = re.sub(r'\n', ",", text_body)
                return final_text
```

This is the element in the main page, and `Ver más respuestas` are located there in each post, just like this one inside red circle.
[image: Main feed]

And by clicking in that `span` element, this shows up, it's a `<div aria-labelledby=":r7q:" role="dialog"` element, that shows up like a pop-up itself.

[image: Dialog element]
Clicking in that `span` See more comments throws that TimeoutError. Hope can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is in your approach. If I understood your problem right is that you want to get the popup data and by pop up I am assuming a hover element. The code is in javascript but the logic will be same in python also.

```
const list-of-locators=await page.locator('span[dir="auto"]:has-text("See more comments")');

for(let i=0; i<list-of-locators.count();i++){
await list-of-locators.nth(i).hover({ timeout: 3000, force: true }) // here we will hover over the first element of the list to get the popup locator
const popUps= await list-of-locators.nth(i).locator('popup')  // here we are inside the first element of list of locators and are getting popups inside that locator
popUps.innerText() // here we can get the inner text of that popup
}
```

Again I assumed by popup you meant to hover over element. If you meant something else then add that detail in your question along with some screenshots of the application

Comment: I just added more info and screenshots, sadly those aren't hover elements.

Comment: So in simple you are clicking on the comment (which you are saying is a span) and it is popping up new comments below right?

Comment: Yes, by clicking in that `span` 'Ver más respuestas', a `role=dialog` appears showing more comments.

Comment: So the approach I used above will be implemented the spans which are opening are the childrens of the dialogue... also try to use the .nth() function of playwright to get child elements

Comment: I tried your solution but doesn't work, I'm getting crazy with this, I don't know what else I can do.